# Getting this error everytime I run any command on cmd

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v14.15.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
```

I tried `npm cache clean`, uninstalling and re installing node, also used registry, yet getting same error

Comment: Your version of npm looks out of date perhaps? Try updating: `npm update -g npm`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer

Deleting the C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm and

Deleting the C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache folder

Done! It should work!